# Sitefinity get current dynamiccontent item from code

Tags: api, content-type, sitefinity

I'm currently writing a site using Sitefinity CMS. Can someone please explain how to get the current dynamic content item from server side code on page_load?

I have written a user control to display a custom gallery of sliding images. There are multiple content types in my dynamic module. The user control will sit as part of the masterpage template rather than on every page. On each page load I would like to fetch the current dynamiccontent item that is associated with the page and examine whether it has a property with the name 'Gallery'. If so I would then extract the images and render them via the usercontrol.

Thanks,

Brian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your images are related content.  This gets every published content item of your type.

```
var dynamicModuleManager = DynamicModuleManager.GetManager();
var moduleType = TypeResolutionService.ResolveType("Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicTypes.Model.YOURTYPEHERE");

var dcItems = dynamicModuleManager.GetDataItems(moduleType)
            .Where(l => l.Status == ContentLifecycleStatus.Master);

foreach (var dcItem in dcItems)
{
   //pass the dynamic content item to a model constructor or populate here, then
   //   get your image this way:

   var image = dcItem.GetRelatedItems<Image>("Images").SingleOrDefault();
   if (image != null)
   {
      ImageUrl = image.MediaUrl;
   }
}
```